# I am trying to change my shell with chsh but I am getting an error

Tags: command-line, 22.04, pam, chsh

I can't change my bash shell to fish with chsh, because it asks for a password, which isn't my root password, and after I type something in I get this: `chsh: PAM: Authentication failure`

This is my `/etc/pam.d/chsh` configuration file:

```
#
# The PAM configuration file for the Shadow `chsh' service
#

# This will not allow a user to change their shell unless
# their current one is listed in /etc/shells. This keeps
# accounts with special shells from changing them.
auth            sufficent       pam_shells.so

# This allows root to change user shell without being
# prompted for a password
auth            sufficent       pam_rootok.so

# The standard Unix authentication modules, used with
# NIS (man nsswitch) as well as normal /etc/passwd and
# /etc/shadow entries.
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session
```

My `/etc/shells` file contains `/bin/fish` and `/usr/bin/fish` too and it still asks for a password. I also know my `sudo` password, but after I type it in, it asks for another one, that I don't know. Like this:

```
gergo@odin:~$ sudo chsh -s /usr/bin/fish
[sudo] password for gergo:  
Password:
chsh: PAM: Authentication failure
```

Please if anyone can think of something tell me.

Comment: Isn't it your user's password?

Comment: `sudo` wants the user's login password. Read `man sudo`.

Comment: Read `man chsh`. For security reasons, `chsh` will only let you change to a shell listed in `/etc/shells`. `grep fish /etc/shells` to see. If it's not there, add it via `type -p fish | sudo tee -a /etc/shells`.

Comment: My /etc/shells file contains `/bin/fish` and `/usr/bin/fish` too and it still asks for a password. I also know my sudo password, but after I type it in it asks for another one, that I don't know. Like this:                            `gergo@odin:~$ sudo chsh -s /usr/bin/fish 
[sudo] password for gergo: 
Password: 
chsh: PAM: Authentication failure
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `/etc/pam.d/chsh`, you need to change:

```
auth            sufficent       pam_shells.so
```

to:

```
auth            required       pam_shells.so
```

And change:

```
auth            sufficent       pam_rootok.so
```

to:

```
auth            sufficient       pam_rootok.so
```

And then, change your own shell without `sudo`, like so:

```
chsh -s /bin/fish
```

---

**Brief explaination:**

`sufficent` is not a valid PAM modules [control flag](https://linux.die.net/man/5/pam.d) and has to be corrected to `sufficient` and furthermore, you don't want it in the first module as it will disable further proper user authentication(*e.g. asking for password*) when returning success to the application immediately and preventing further stack processing, so use `required` instead ... Also using `sudo chsh -s /usr/bin/fish` without specifying a user like `sudo chsh -s /usr/bin/fish username` will change `root`'s login shell and not yours and you don't need `sudo` for changing your own login shell, so don't use it.